# Did Arjun become favourite of Krishna because of Indra?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, indra, arjuna

I read somwhere that Indra had asked Krishna to take care of his(Indra's) son Arjun when Indra met  Krishna at the time when Krishna lifted the Govardhan.

So, Was it because of Indra, Arjun became favourite of Krisna ?

Or Was Arjun favourite of Krishna even before his birth ? (Both Krishna and Arjun took birth on the same day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No.

Though Lord Krishna said this to Lord Indra.

MBH. Harivamsa Parva 2:19:101.:

> “shakra (indra)! Whatever your son Arjuna asks me, I will do as a servant, because I am bound by your affection.”.

But Lord Krishna loved Arjuna irrespective of that also.

MBH 10:12:27.:

> “Other than Phalguna I have no dearer friend on earth, that friend to whom there is nothing that I cannot give including my very wives and children…”

Again,

Section LXXIX, Abhimanyu badha Parva in Book 7.: Droṇa Parva.:

> My wives, my kinsmen, my relatives, none amongst these is dearer to me than Arjuna. O Daruka, I shall not be able to cast my eyes, even for a single moment, on the earth bereft of Arjuna.

Plus,

Book 7. Drona Vadha Parva.: SECTION CCI.:

> Even that God now walketh the earth (as Vasudeva), beguiling the universe by his illusion. From Narayana's asceticism was born a great Muni of the name of Nara, equal to Narayana himself. Know that Arjuna is none else than that Nara. Those two Rishis, said to be older than the oldest gods, take their births in every Yuga for serving the purposes of the world.

So, Lord Krishna Loved Arjuna and Lord Indra equally.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 2):

Arjuna and Krishna were the sages Nara and Narayana in their previous birth. They were sons of Dharma and Incarnations of Lord Vishnu.

'

> You are mine and I am thine, while all that is mine is thine also! He
> that hates you hates me as well, and he that follows you follows me!
> **O you irrepressible one, you are Nara and I am Narayana or Hari! We are the Rishis Nara and Narayana born in the world of men for a
> special purpose.** O Partha, you are from me and I am from you! O bull
> of the Bharata race, no one can understand the difference that is
> between us!'

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7287.html

> ****With one body Hari will become the son of Vasudeva,** and will thence be called Vasudeva; and with the other he will be the son of
> Pandu and will thereby be named the Pandava Arjuna or Arjuna the
> Pandava.**

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118596.html

So no. Indra has no role in relationship between Arjuna and Krishna. They were brothers in previous birth and were born on earth together to destroy Adharma.